# ¿Cómo sustituyo un elemento por otro de la mismo vector, condicionado al elemento de otro vector?

Tags: base-de-datos, r, condiciones, dataframe, rstudio

En mi Data Frame `df_lab3` tengo 6 columna, entre ellas `edo_nac_fac` y `dist_unif`

En la columna `edo_nac_fac` debo sustituir mi elemento **Colima** por el elemento **Tabasco**, pero solo en aquellos casos  en los que en la columna `dist_unif` sea **menor de 25**.

No estoy segura si utilizar `ifelse` o `replace`
Agradecería su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Si `replace()` es la función base, entonces no tienes forma de indicar una condición de reemplazo. Con `ifelse()` sin duda puedes resolverlo:

```
df_lab3$edo_nac_fac <- ifelse(df_lab3$edo_nac_fac == 'Colima' & df_lab3$dist_unif < 25,
                              "Tabasco",
                              df_lab3$edo_nac_fac)
```

Pero también podrías hacer algo más directo, modificando el valor solo en las filas que cumplen la condición:

```
df_lab3[df_lab3$edo_nac_fac == 'Colima' & df_lab3$dist_unif < 25, "edo_nac_fac"] <- "Tabasco"
```